# Why does my script work when started from console but does not work when started via upstart?

Tags: command-line, upstart

I am running Ubuntu 12.04.
Here is what I am trying to do:

I copied and adapted a shell script from here: http://yatse.leetzone.org/redmine/boards/2/topics/2088. It listens to UDP port 9 for Wake-On-LAN packages. When it receives a package, it should start xbmc. Here is the script /home/myusername/.xbmc/autostarter:

```
#!/bin/bash
UDP_PORT=9          # Change this if you need to run this on a different port

START_PHRASE="E.....@"    
START_PHRASE_ESCAPED="E\.\.\.\.\.@"    

# The following block checks if the user running this script has the required      privileges to listen on the port specified above
WHO=`whoami`
if [ "$WHO" != "root" ]; then
     echo "Cannot start unless running as root." >> /var/log/xbmc-starter.log
  exit 1
fi

echo "Listening on port $UDP_PORT for start command" >> /var/log/xbmc-starter.log

while [ true ]; do
     # Wait for a packet to come in
     LISTEN=`tcpdump "udp port $UDP_PORT" -A -c 1 2>&1 | grep -o    "$START_PHRASE_ESCAPED"`
     # Make sure that we received the right command
     if [ "$LISTEN" = "$START_PHRASE" ]; then
        echo "Starting XBMC" >> /var/log/xbmc-starter.log
        /usr/bin/xbmc 
        echo "test log after command" >> /var/log/xbmc-starter.log
     fi
     # Sleep, to be nice, for unwanted rogue processes writing to our port
     sleep 1
done
```

When I run this script from command line with sudo and send the WOL package, it works and starts xbmc.

```
sudo ./autostarter
```

The log output is:

```
Listening on port 9 for start command
Starting XBMC
test log after command
```

But when I run it from an upstart script, it creates the same log output but does not start xbmc. Here is my upstart script xbmc-starter.conf:

```
# Starts a listener that runs the xbmc start script when a WOL package is received
description     "start xbmc wol listener script"
# runlevels
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]
exec /home/myusername/.xbmc/autostarter
```

And the log output:

```
Listening on port 9 for start command
Starting XBMC
test log after command
```

Why doesn't it start XBMC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe adding `env DISPLAY=:0` to the Upstart job would help? I think XBMC needs to be able to know what display to use, you know?

Comment: Thanks, I already tried that but it had no effect. But it seems that I have to do this also in addition to the solution of the other Problem.

Comment: Maybe adding --standalone to xbmc's options would work.

Comment: Your first suggestion was part of the solution! See my comment on the other answer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a shot, since no one else has offered an answer.

Try changing your start condition to `start on started tty1`

My understanding of init systems is that they will happily start programs at weird times if you ask them to.  Asking to start at the run levels could mean at the beginning of those run levels, before anything else has started.  Like before things like any part of the file system have been mounted, and certainly before minimal networking is available.

start on started tty1 will wait till the first terminal is started before starting the program, which is basically the same time that you would be able to run/test things manually.  So your program starts up later in the boot process, but you should get more consistent results.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that is the problem. The log output suggests that the script is started correctly and that tcpdump receives the WOL package correctly. Otherwise it could not have entered the if-block and logged the last two lines. The problem seems to be with the execution of the xbmc command.

Comment: OK, fair enough.  FWIW, I am confident that the syntax I gave you will work.  It is the simple way to have a script start up on bootup, per some guide I read.
If you DO give it a try, let me know if it still doesn't work.  I'm curious.

Comment: and maybe check the xbmc.log file to see if there are any errors there.  gl

Comment: Ok, I tried "start on started tty1". First, the result didn't change. BUT:
I also wrote a simpler script for testing that just waits 10 seconds and then starts XBMC (without any network foo). This script had the same Problem. But then I tried this script with "start on started tty1" and the result was weird:
1. Ubuntu didn't boot anymore. Black screen, no GUI no CLI available. 
2. Boot in recovery mode into resume normal boot. Suddenly xbmc starts immediatly.
3. Boot normally again - ubuntu still won't start. I had to change the script back in recovery mode. What does all that mean?

Comment: I did some testing on my machine.  I just used sleep 30, run xbmc for my script.  For me, changing the upstart configs didn't do anything, nor cause any of the issues you had.  But, I did see that xbmc was segfaulting when being started this way.  So my suggestion is clearly incorrect.  
You may need to run xbmc as a certain user, and not as root.  I would see if you can just get xbmc to autostart, before working on the remote thing.

Comment: Solved it! It was two things combined. First, I have to start xbmc with the user i am logged in with and NOT with root (as the upstart script does). So I changed the xbmc command to "sudo -u myusername /usr/bin/xbmc". The second thing was almost what CameronNemo suggested, only that my Display is named :0.0 apparently. So adding "export DISPLAY=:0.0" before starting xbmc finally did the trick. So thanks to both of you for helping me on my way to the solution! I would upvote but it seems that I do not have enough reputation yet.